# How to import a .mtl file?

Tags: objects, import

I am new to Blender. I downloaded a `.obj` file of a plant model. When I unzipped it I found two files (`.obj` and `.mtl`). 
I imported the .obj file and I couldn't do the same with the `.mtl` to apply the material and the textures.

Comment: When you import the obj it should read the associated .mtl file by default. Are you sure you aren't in wireframe view? Press `Z` to toggle this on/off.

Comment: i am having a similar problem where the mtl is showing in the 3d view but not in the rendered view. i cannot find an answer for this anywhere

Comment: @swim You probably don't have a texture on the object.

Answer (score 39):

When you import the `.obj` file, Blender will also import the associated `.mtl` file* by default as well which is usually the same name. The colors applied to the model will show in the viewport and to see the texture(s) (if any), enable texture shading with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

<sup>* *This is the file that should be generated alongside the obj when it was created and will hold color data and paths to textures if any. Opening the obj file in a text editor should show this near the top.*</sup>

Comment: Also note, the textures won't show in the model editor. You need to go to "Shading" to see them

Comment: You may need to edit the plain text .mtl file. I just ran into this as the delivered .mtl file referred to two texture images with a hard coded Windows path.