# Blender isn't importing mtl correctly with obj?

Tags: import, obj

I'm a new blender user, but have used other modelling programs before.

I've downloaded a [model file](http://www.models-resource.com/nintendo_64/pokemonsnap/model/4949/) and unzipped it.

When I import the obj into blender, it is my understanding (from here: [How to import a .mtl file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/how-to-import-a-mtl-file)) that the mtl should just import itself with it. However, when I import the obj, I just get a grey model with no texture. Is it actually importing the mtl but I'm not seeing it? Also for the record, I have changed no settings in blender.

Picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I've got an OBJ with MTL and PNG files but Blender seems to ignore them. Both MTL and PNG have the same file name and are in the same directory... the only posted answer wasn't much help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have your viewport shading set to *Textured* to see any textures or materials on the imported model. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to textured view or alternatively, open the properties panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and under *Shading*, tick *Textured Solid*.

[image] 
[image]

*(Click the images for a higher res.*)

Answer (score 1):

Try copying any accompanying .PNG files into the same directory as the .MTL file, then edit the contents of the .MTL file to remove any directory references relating to the .PNG files.

Import the .OBJ file again, and F12 render.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the only light in your scene is inside your imported model (was with mine!). Either move the light or delete it to see your model with textures

Comment: This doesn't really look like the problem.