# Importing OBJ with MTL and Image not working properly

Tags: import, obj

I'm trying to import an OBJ file that has associated MTL and PNG files. There's a similar question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7920/blender-isnt-importing-mtl-correctly-with-obj), but the answer is not very helpful, I just see a big blob.

[These are the files](http://rll.berkeley.edu/amazon_picking_challenge/data/champion_copper_plus_spark_plug/processed.tgz) that I'm trying to import. Inside the textured meshes folder there's a few different versions of the object but none seem to import correctly with the texture applied.

I also don't have access to the material and object (as well as a few other) buttons. (see the picture)

[image]

Blender 2.71

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### 1. Check the obj file

In your case the obj is not exported correctly. **Obj** is a [human readable file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) it is easy to find the issue. You can check this by open up the file in a text editor of your choice (sublime, gedit...).

To check referenced materials go to these lines:

- `mtllib [external .mtl file name]`
- `usemtl [material name]`

In your case `mtllib` line is correct, but `usemtl` is missing.

```
# OBJ FILE
...
f 3103/18700/18700 3081/18701/18700 3119/18702/18700
f 279/18703/18703 3118/18704/18703 274/18705/18703
f 265/18706/18706 3101/18707/18706 278/18708/18706

# usemtl material name (reference to the .mtl file)
usemtl MyMaterialName
```

You can find the material name in the **mtl** file in this line: `newmtl [material name]`

```
# MTL FILE
newmtl MyMaterialName
Ka 1.000 1.000 1.000     # white
Kd 1.000 1.000 1.000     # white
Ks 0.000 0.000 0.000     # black (off)
map_Ka myMap.jpg         # ambient texture map
...
```

As last step check if the paths to the textures are *correct*:

```
map_Ka my-texture.jpg                           # points to texture in obj folder
map_Ka /home/user/images/my-texture.jpg         # absolute path on unix
map_Ka C:\\Users\\user\\images\\my-texture.jpg  # absolute path on windows
```

Make sure that the filenames of your textures are correct and there are no *white spaces* in the paths itself. Instead of pointing to the 'absolute path', you can also try Blenders [Find Missing Files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink) operator. For further information about all the possibilities of obj's read this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).

### 2. Apply the material

If the material is not applied to the imported object you can select it here:

[image]

### 3. Enable textures in the viewport

- If your textures are *pink*, see: [Why are all the textures in my file pink?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5368/why-are-all-the-textures-in-my-file-pink)
- To display the texture in the viewport see: [How to show textures in the 3D View editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-to-show-textures-in-editor)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work, I don't get the material button in the scene as you show... I only get the options shown in the picture I posted.

Comment: ok, got the button thing figured out, but after changing the material it still doesn't display the texture on the mesh. Is there some other option that I need to change?

Comment: Ok, finally, took me a while since I don't know blender very well. Your solution works great, I was just missing the step to go into the UV/Image Editor and make the changes there as well.

Comment: 1) I changed the texture as you showed. 2) Went into edit 3) changed the image in the UI/Image editor. Then everything looked like it should. Here's a pic showing where I did these things if it's not clear. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65115630/blender.jpeg

Comment: In general texture is applied to diffuse layer(`map_Kd`) rather than ambient layer(`map_Ka`)

Comment: Although that's correct @neckTwi, I did not mention anything about that...  linked the wikipedia article however. Such comments wasting time IMO. If you think that this additional information is relevant in this case and you are really interested in helping future visitors, then please improve my answer (by suggesting an edit) instead. Thanks

Comment: I am just checking my understanding of 3D. I have just gone through OpenGL tutorials recently. Thank you for confirming that I am right. sorry!

Comment: map_Ka what its for?

Answer (score 2):

Having had this issue on multiple occasions and resolving it by manually editing the MTL file with `map_Kd texture.png`.

The cause ended up being that creating a Shader Node in Blender 2.8 material with `Image Texture > Material Output` wasn't enough for Blender to parse the flow graph for the texture details, and it was necessary to create the material like this:

`Image Texture > Principled BSDF > Material Output`.

Comment: Thank you. That solved my issue.