# Decimating a Mesh that has an associated texture file?

Tags: mesh

I have a mesh in OBJ format (that I did not generate) that comes with an associated MTL and PNG file.

Can I decimate the mesh and still have the texture display properly?

[An example mesh](http://rll.berkeley.edu/amazon_picking_challenge/data/champion_copper_plus_spark_plug/processed.tgz) that I would like to decimate. See the textured meshes folder.

Note that the obj file needs a quick fix as noted in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-png).

Comment: I assume these are scanned?  One of the founders of Sketchfab has been doing some pretty nice scans and he's very friendly and interested in talking to people. https://sketchfab.com/alban  If you post some questions on his model posts I'm sure he'll be happy to give you some tips.  Several people at cgcookie.com spend a lot of time on retopology so you may want to check them out as well.

Comment: So far as preserving UV's through Decimation goes, that tends to work well when the mesh is all quads and those quads flow along well defined loops(decimate Modifier).  I have had success using the Remove Doubles tool set to a high Merge Distance to reduce models such as the ones you've posted and it does work well at preserving the UV's but it does tend to create some overlapping geometry when used like this.  I think you will have to try several techniques to see what works best for whatever situation you happen to be working on since what you are asking is very involved.

Comment: You may also want to look into building simple meshes completely in Blender and then ray-tracing the detail from the high-poly model onto the low-poly model.  With Blender that's often called Baking with Selected To Active.

Comment: @MarcClintDion thanks! I thought it might be a simple operation that I just wasn't aware of in Blender. I'll give your suggestions a go an post what worked best when I'm done.