# Is there a way to Import old 3ds max files into blender

Tags: import

I have models from an old game called Trespasser that were made on 3ds max back around 1998, and I cant figure out how to see or use them in blender.  I can provide one as a sample if needed, but I would like to see these models, and use them if possible.

Thank you

I do not have 3ds max software, but I also did not realize they had a trial version, so I may do as suggested. I also did not see anything about this in the forum, so I do apologize about the duplicate question.

EDIT : I cannot install  3ds max 2015, for some reason, but assuming it has to do with me using Windows Vista Ultimate instead of 7 or 8. I am looking into other means.

Thank you for the help though, maybe I can figure it out now.

Comment: I am new to blender, and learning through all the tutorials I am finding across the internet.  I have gathered information for all kinds of applications to use for multiple reasons.

Comment: Welcome Bryan :) Unfortunatly it's not possible to import **.max** files directly. You have to export it. Best practice is to export them from 3ds max as **.obj**, because it's a human readable file format, See this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024 Anyway, enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

click file, immport and then choose which format do you have. I don't know, what formats 3ds max uses but I'm sure you can export it as .stl or .obj[image: import]