# Changing an MTL on an OBJ file

Tags: texturing, import

So I'm a bit new to Blender and I've ran into a bit of a problem.  I modeled out an object and imported the OBJ file, which grabbed the MTL automatically, which is awesome.  Now my problem is I noticed some issues on the MTL, coloring wise, and changed some stuff but I can't seem to get the changes to reflect in Blender.  Any help would be awesome, thanks guys.

Comment: wait.. are you modifying the MTL file, and expecting the change to propagate back to your .blend file? The two aren't linked, once you export  it's separate.

Comment: I understand that the changes would not show unless I take certain steps.  But I have tried importing the MTL back into the project and can't seem to figure out how to use it instead of the original it was imported with.

Comment: I'm not sure i'm following. What you can do is make a really simple object (maybe a cube...) and apply materials / texture to it. and then export and look at those files in a plain-text-editor, you'll see how they're linked. It's kind of beyond the scope of BlenderSE and more to do with a specific file type. Try my suggestion, get a better grasp of what an .mtl and .obj file are.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024