# Material importing and exporting problems (wavefront .obj format)

Tags: materials, export, import

Very new to Blender, and I was wondering what I am doing wrong if the material shows up in renders (while in cycles), but when I export the .obj, and then import it again, the material is only applied to a fraction of the model.

Comment: probably your export settings are not correct, for importing objs see this related answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024 Please add more information and preferably your blend file to the question. You can upload it here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you're in Cycles apply your color to the viewport color of the mesh. The exporter will use this value. This option is located under Settings in the Materials-Panel.