# Material isn't loading properly from the imported .obj file

Tags: rendering, import

Only the color loads properly from the material and other settings are missing when in load the exported obj file.

this is the first rendered image:

[image]

And this is the image rendered after importing the .obj file:

[image]

So my question is, where are the other settings which you can see in the first rendered image

Comment: Does this help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024 ?

Comment: Would need the .blend/.obj files to confirm, but this is most likely a limitation of .OBJ material description, which is very basic. Henceforce, it’s hard and quite limited to convert a Blender material to it (actually, Cycle nodes are even not used at all iirc when exporting).