# Texture-less/colourless .obj file when opened

Tags: modeling, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an MMD model which i exported from PMD/PMX editor in .obj format, but when I import it into blender (ver. 2.75a), it's missing it's textures, same thing happens when I open it in Keyshot, anyway to fix this/re-colour textures? [image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024

Answer (score 1):

`Obj` files do not store color/texture information. However, it can contain a reference to an `*.mtl` file.

- You can check the `obj` file content and look if it contains a reference to an `mtl` file - which itself stores the colors of points/textures
- Or maybe you can use another format when exporting (`ply` does store color information for each point for example).