# Unable to export textures with .obj files

Tags: texturing, objects, export

I have created a model and added textures to it using Cycles rendering engine. When I export to .obj file the textures are not saved with the object. I tried given copy in the path while exporting the textures are getting copied to the directory but I am unable to get the output. Also .obj, .mtl and all textures are stored in the same directory without spaces in their names. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I save something as an OBJ file the texture does not save with it, why?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/when-i-save-something-as-an-obj-file-the-texture-does-not-save-with-it-why)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I think it's possible duplicate of [When I save something as an OBJ file the texture does not save with it, why?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/when-i-save-something-as-an-obj-file-the-texture-does-not-save-with-it-why)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the import and export properties are like below:

For importing make sure **Image Search** is checked:

[image]

For exporting make sure **Write Materials** is checked:

[image]