# Export obj files with textures from Project

Tags: texturing, export, obj

I am new to blender and I have a blender project ([link](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/science/medical/forceps-tweezer-pincette-medical-instruments)) which contains several objects. I want to export each object as an obj file with material and complete texture information. Yet, if I export the files I only end up with the obj and .mtl file without the textures, e.g. the mtl-file does not contain the map_Kd command and the image files do not appear. The textures all lie in an external folder next to the blender project. These are the option when exporting. If I did not provide enough information I apologize! The option "Write materials" like in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121650/unable-to-export-textures-with-obj-files) does not appear.
Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To export all of your meshes as separate objects select objects which you want to export go to *Scripting* workspace and in side of it go to *Templates > Python > Batch Export* and change line 29 to be

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=fn + ".obj", use_selection=True)
```

and that press "play button".

For textures see this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47950/12996)