# Converting blend file to wavefront obj file

Tags: export

I am trying to convert a blend file into OBJ file. The file in question is : [Birch Tree Free 3D](https://free3d.com/3d-model/birch-tree-48016.html).

Now, I don't have any idea about blender or rendering for the matter. I want to use OBJ file format for course-project. I want to convert this to an OBJ file and a single Texture Image, thus preferably without any references to MTL files. All the UV coordinates should map to single image. I don't care about Texture options in mtl files either.

Simply exporting the blend file simply creates a obj file and mtl file, and NO texture files at all.
I am unable to bake the image either. ( Error : Circular Reference in Texture Stack )
Also, Path does not contain spaces or anything.

I have enabled write materials (+ Copy) while exporting still no Image files are generated.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I save something as an OBJ file the texture does not save with it, why?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/when-i-save-something-as-an-obj-file-the-texture-does-not-save-with-it-why)

Comment: I have enabled write materials, and it is set to copy too. Path and filenames don't have spaces either.  I am unable to bake it either. (Circular ref in texture stack)