# obj Import .mtl File

Tags: import

Hey I'm struggling with an obj File. I got an obj file and everything seems fine except the Textures are missing. I checked the .mtl file and the .obj file.

I've already looked at [Importing OBJ with MTL and Image not working properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly)

In the .obj File at the start of the File it looks like this after I've replaced an absolute path in mtllib:

```
# FILE 11740_Baumgartu_Haus_0_3D-Export.obj
mtllib 11740_Baumgartu_Haus_0_3D-Export.mtl
trace_obj 11740_Baumgartu_Haus_0_3D-Export.obj
shadow_obj 11740_Baumgartu_Haus_0_3D-Export.obj

g C211_AUSSENWAND_TR VERPUTZ__GLATT__WEISS

usemtl VERPUTZ__GLATT__WEISS

v -24948.3 -6963.67 8330
v -24903.8 -7471.73 8330
v -24704.6 -7454.3 8330
v -24749 -6946.24 8330
v -25012.6 -7146.54 8570
v -25028 -6970.64 8570
...
```

and in the mtl file it looks like this:

```
# FILE:11740_Baumgartu_Haus_0_3D-Export.obj
newmtl VERPUTZ__GLATT__WEISS
Ka 0.916471 0.916471 0.916471
Kd 0.964706 0.964706 0.964706
Ks 0 0 0
illum 2
Ns 100
map_Ka verputz_glatt_weiss.jpg
map_Kd verputz_glatt_weiss.jpg
map_Ks verputz_glatt_weiss.jpg
newmtl 011740_FASSADE_FENSTERBAND
Ka 0.4 0.4 0.376471
Kd 0.633333 0.633333 0.596078
Ks 0.25 0.25 0.25
illum 2
Ns 5
...
```

The textures are placed in the Folder "11740_Baumgartu_Haus_0_3D-Export_Texturen" inside the Folder where the obj and mtl file is. I have copied the textures directly into the same folder as the mtl and obj aswell.
Can't find what is still missing

In Blender it looks like this: [image: missing texture]

when importing I have set the search images checkbox

Comment: From your screen capture, it seems that the object is not selected/active (it is appearing in orange and not in yellow). Is it the same if it is the active object (RMB on it) ?

Comment: Yes I can select one of the objects and it's the same. If i enable Textures in the Viewport shader they are not applied.

Comment: I think Blender may show the textures objects even if it is not able to find the textures files. So... if you dont have any textures objects in Blender, this is not a path problem, but a textures objects problem ?

Comment: Please, add a screen capture of the object textures once the object is selected as active, in order to see if the textures are defined on it (not the rendering, but the texture data in the texture panel)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2cubtKA.jpg

Comment: OK. The material does not show the image. Could you have a look to the UV/Image editor and check if the textures are there ? If they are not : you'll have to add them. If they are, you'll have to link them to the materials. Sometimes, downloaded files are not perfect...

Comment: They do not show up in the UV/Image editor, the model stays gray when rendered. So guess it's manual work from this point on? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Probably yes : manual work. But often material and texture names are more or less similar (I hope this is the case for you...).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the name in the code (mtllib Name.mtl) from the OBJ file is the same as the MTL file name.

If it's not please tweak the code or change the name of the MTL file.
This issue happened to me too when i realised the OBJ file doesn't have the same name
in the code.

If this doesn't work and/or the filename was the same then there
is probably an issue with the code. If the code doesn't match the pictures name's then you schould modify the names.

~Randy