# Materials / Textures in DXF file

Tags: texturing, file-format

I have created a new scene, deleted everything and set the "3D view far clipping distance" at 10000. Then I imported a DXF file (since it was in mm I did set the unit scale at 1000 and I also checked "center geometry to scene"). After "Align View / Center Cursor and View All" this is my scene:

[image]

The creator of this file told me that this 3D model should contain geometry, materials and textures (all created in FORMZ). Now other SE contributor already told me that most of the time imported textures will be useless but I want to know where I can find the materials / textures in this imported DXF file ? I only see geometry in this imported file.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK [`dxf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD_DXF) neither supports uv's nor textures.

Comment: I agree with Poor, DXF is a CAD format, with basic support for meshes only. I don't think UVs are supported, neither are material definitions, and even if they are, I'm not sure Blender importer knows how to read them properly. Aside from that, as far as I know DXF files don't have the ability to embed data like images or textures inside the file, as far as I know. So unless you got some external files along with the DXF, I don't think you will be able to get any textures.