# MTL file with wrong data?

Tags: texturing

I purchased this [3D model of the CN tower](http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/cn-tower-3d-model/815641). I want to import it in Blender, but when importing it, the 3D model has no texture.

I searched the Web for a while and stumbled on a thread where someone recommended to take a look at the .MTL file and see if the materials' paths were correct. What weirded me out, is that the materials in the .mtl file and the file names in the "Textures" folder are completely different. To illustrate:

[image]

The reference for this "usemtl" is "wire_148177027", yet in the "Textures" folder, there is no file with such a name. All of the JPEGs in this folder have very normal names, such as "Metal6.jpg", "Wall4.jpg", etc. Where does the association happen? Isn't there supposed to be a correlation between the value of "usemtl" and the file names? If no, where can I find it?

I wouldn't mind rebuilding the materials in Blender, except that I have no idea what image to apply to material names such as "wire_148177027", so this is pretty darn frustrating...

The value of "mtllib" is correct.

All of the textures are in the same folder as the OBJ and .MTL folder and the paths in the .MTL file are relative, as such : "map_Ka Greenish_Brick.jpg", etc.

Any help/guidance would be greatly(!) appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just opened the .MTL file in a text editor (had only opened the OBJ file in the editor) and realized that the map_Kd links were completely wrong, so I fixed them (direct paths), but unfortunately it still doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Yes, absolute paths is a classical import road blocker with obj. Then you have to fix the entries in the mtl file one by one. You might have still not the right the path to the textures. Are the textures in a folder besides the obj file? Then you might get away by using map_Kd .\mytexture.png . But best is to put the textures completely besides the obj file. And use map_kd mytexture.png

Comment: Does this question relate to blender?

Comment: Absolutely. Blender has an obj importer :)

Comment: @Tiles Blender also loads png files but that doesn't mean that questions about fixing corrupt pngs would be on-topic here.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, i see your point, but png is not obj. obj is one of the most open 3D file formats around. You could write the whole obj file by hand when you want. And as told, the absolute texture path is one of the most common and most easy to fix issues with it. Because the obj and mtl file is simple and plain text. I would even go so far to say that the knowledge to make the texture path relative in the obj files by hand is necessary to work with obj.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't appear to be a question about blender.

Comment: @Justin01 related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24024/3710

Comment: And i vote to keep it because fixing the texture path is a common and reqired action to work with obj.

Comment: @Tiles Your intentions are good, but this is not the place to fix corrupt obj files. They were not originally created with Blender, exported or imported into Blender, nor is the final destination in Blender. Blender is not even used in the process of fixing them, so this may belong in a forum or another Stack Exchange site like Power Users or Stack Overflow, or something like that

Comment: That's imho the point. It's not corrupt nor does the issue live outside Blender. The paths are absolute, that's all. And it is a common operation to make them relative again. It's an import export issue. You can easily produce such "corrupt" obj files with Blender. Just use absolute paths and export as obj. Then move the result into another folder and try to load it back into Blender.

Comment: @RayMairlot I apologize if I didn't make it seem like it was related to Blender. I realize now that I did not mention Blender even once in the troubleshooting part of my post, even though I was trying to fix the whole problem through Blender and Sublime. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: @Tiles I'd like to thank you for your responses thus far. Like I said in the above message, I was vague about my use of Blender, but I can assure everyone here that I _am_ trying to resolve this through Blender. Now, about the location of the textures, I've put them in the same folder as my OBJ and .MTL files and changed all the paths to just "map_Kd Greenish_Brick.jpg", etc. in my .MTL file. Still no luck unfortunately... I am now trying out the solution in poor's link, even if I remember trying it out last night. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Justin01 If you have more information to add to the question or want to clarify something then you can use the [edit] link below the question. If the question gets edited it will be pushed into a review queue and may get re-opened if people feel the 'close reason' is no longer valid.

Comment: @RayMairlot Thank you for the fast response Ray. I've replaced "Element 3D" with "Blender" in my post, as I'm experiencing the exact same problem in both and I'd rather solve this issue in Blender. Thanks again.

Comment: @poor Thank you for the link, but I've already tried this solution and it does not appear to be working. I can't see any of the bitmap textures in the list of Materials in step 2 of your link. They're simply not there, even if my paths in the .MTL file are correct. Bummer... Thanks again.

Comment: @RayMairlot Given that my submission was put on hold for a while, which dimished its chances of getting answers/responses, combined with the fact that I have yet to solve my problem... would it be acceptable for me to delete it and start a new one? Thank you.

Comment: @Justin01 You shouldn't delete and re-ask just to try and get it noticed. SE has several methods for making sure even old questions become visible. Editing alone pushes it to the top of the 'active questions' page as does receiving 'up votes'.

Comment: @Justin01 I've updated [my answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24024/3710). Without having a look into the `mtl` file, it's only guessing... However, it's a strictly defined file type (there is some logic behind) so there must be a way importing the files properly. If my answer doesn't help, I'd suggest read the wikipedia article carefully.