# Import 3D model from CityEngine into Blender and edit UV Map

Tags: modeling, uv, import, collada

I really would like to learn about UV mapping and I presume this is the best community for me to ask about Blender. I have a 3D building model produced from [CityEngine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/cityengine/) and when it was exported into collada (.dae file) -or even .obj file- all its textures are stored in one folder. I mean, there are alot of images stored. I was searching for a means to merge these images into one image file and I have this UV mapping researched. I would like to ask how would I do that in blender. Can somebody help me edit my model and have the UV mapping in blender? I don't know where to start, I have importd my model into blender yet none of the textures were displayed. it's all white. I really appreciate help from you nad God bless.

Comment: Are you using Blender Render or Cycles Render?

Comment: I'm sorry Sir i don't know about that. .I am new to Blender. . I was not able to explore further about Blender. the only thing I have gone so far is to load my 3D building into Blender, that's all. .

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7921/599

Comment: @King635, in my view, your project UV mapping an imported model from CityEngine, in Blender is like deciding to learn woodworking, and using this [table](http://www.timothy-corrigan.com/p/LouisXIVTable.jpg) as your first project. As I would advise you to choose another, less demanding project while learning to use the tools of woodworking, I suggest gaining facility with the tools in the Blender "toolbox" before tackling the UV mapping of the import. A good place to start this is the online courses under learning in [question 15355](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355)

Comment: It might be useful to those who might wish to help you more completely, to upload a copy of your blend file to [Blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and post a link in your question so that those inclined to try to help could access the blend file causing your confusion. Exactly what the best way to combine the images into a smaller number will depend exactly on details of the images themselves.

Answer (score 1):

To UV Unwrap your model, Go to Edit mode of your object and select all the mesh, then press <kbd>U</kbd> on your keyboard to open UV Mapping options and select smart UV project,

[image]

after change your window mode to UV mapping,

[image]

and finally open the texture you want to give to your object in the bottom bar,

[image]

once you opened you can scale and move your UV map untill it matches your texture how you want it.To scale press <kbd>S</kbd> key, to move press <kbd>G</kbd> key

[image]

Comment: I have already textures on my model. do these textures automatically mapped on its corresponding UV or there is a need for me to apply textures again . . Honestly, when I load my 3Dmodel into blender, these textures doesn't appear.

Comment: you have to open your own textures, I just gave an example of a texture, also opening texture in UV will not really give your object a texture, you have to go to materials tab in properties panel to apply a texture