# Importing OBJ with MTL and PNG doesn't work

Tags: obj

I have very simple OBJ, MTL, PNG files which are linked.
[Here's my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VC65-GelETugx75nuC2JSTw5IgRzd78L/view?usp=sharing) (There are my local path in OBJ, MTL files)

I can open OBJ with texture in 3D viewer (windows basic program).
[image]

But when I import Wavefront(.obj) in Blender, I cannot see the image texture.

[image]

I wanna do that in Blender because I need some features in it.

There's similar questions, But the answer is not very helpful. [link1](http://rll.berkeley.edu/amazon_picking_challenge/data/champion_copper_plus_spark_plug/processed.tgz) [link2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7920/blender-isnt-importing-mtl-correctly-with-obj)

Please help me open files with texture in Blender.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: You have to change the viewport shading to "Material Preview". Click on the third ball icon on the right upper corner in the "3D View" field.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!