# How to import tga files texture information into Blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, import, texture-painting

I just received a 3D model including one **obj** and two **tga** files that are generated in 3dx Max.

When I import the **obj** file into Blender, obviously I cannot see the texture details provided by **tga** files.

The **obj** file contains a line referring to an **mtl** file with the same name which does not exist.

How can I convert texture information of tga files such that I can import and see them in blender?

I've read somewhere that I should convert **tga** file into **png** or **jpg** format.

Then what?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no need to change tga files to anything else, blender can import that format. The issue is that the object has no materials or they have not been been assigned to the object. Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/importing-obj-with-mtl-and-image-not-working-properly/24024#24024

Comment: maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7790/how-can-i-get-a-mtl-file-to-show-on-an-obj-model-i-imported-in-cycles and also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/how-to-import-a-mtl-file

Comment: Yes, TGA files are just fine on their own, your problem is that OBJ import doesn't necessarily create good materials for you automatically.