# mtl is not importing with obj

Tags: modeling, import, obj

[How to import a .mtl file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/how-to-import-a-mtl-file)

I have read many questions like this one above and cant seem to find one that helps. I downloaded a mewtwo model from here (https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-print-models/miniatures/figurines/mewtwo-figure-3d) it comes with both the OBJ file and the MTL file. Both are named the same and when the obj is imported the model doesn't have any color or texture added to it. Do I just keep finding OBJ models with bad MTL's, or is there something I need to turn on to allow blender to automatically apply the MTL like It's supposed to do?

Comment: The model has no material information. The mtl file is empty and there are no materials or groups in the obj file. It looks like you just keep finding OBJ models with bad MTLs.

Comment: How are you able to tell all that. So that way ill know what to look for, and I'll know I'm just not messing up

Comment: I've written more than one obj file loader. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [obj format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) is well documented and text-based. It can be opened in any good text editor. In the case of this model, the MTL file contains only two lines, both are comments from the exporter.

In the obj file: the vertices are the lines that begin with a "v" followed by three numbers. If there were texture coordinates, they would be on lines beginning with "vt". Faces are defined with lines that start with "f", if there are vertex groups or materials, they would show up with "g" or "usemtl" mixed in with the face data. Mewtwo has one "g" before the start of the faces and no "usemtl"